# Is there an alternative to "_api/web/siteusers" or "_api/web/sitegroups" that is able to return both groups and users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, groups, person-or-group

Is there an alternative to `_api/web/siteusers` or `_api/web/sitegroups` that is able to return both groups and users?

I'm looking for a way to return the person OR group title from a SharePoint item using `getbyid()`.

I want a single solution that can return the title whether it's a group or a person. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch items from SharePoint list (`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('')/items`) with person or group column?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch person or group column details from SharePoint list items, use SharePoint REST API endpoint in below format:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items?$select=Title,PersonColumn/Title&$expand=PersonColumn
```

It will return correct title for both the cases correctly.

**List data**:

[image]

**REST API Output** (example):

```
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/PersonColumn" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="PersonColumn" href="Web/Lists(guid'7568b3cc-bbab-4582-a5ad-51b465d92869')/Items(1)/PersonColumn">
    <m:inline>
        <entry>
            <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:Title>Megan Bowen</d:Title>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </m:inline>
</link>
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:Title>Item 1</d:Title>
    </m:properties>
</content>

<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/PersonColumn" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="PersonColumn" href="Web/Lists(guid'7568b3cc-bbab-4582-a5ad-51b465d92869')/Items(1)/PersonColumn">
    <m:inline>
        <entry>
            <category term="SP.Data.UserInfoItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
                <m:properties>
                    <d:Title>JSONFormatting Members</d:Title>
                </m:properties>
            </content>
        </entry>
    </m:inline>
</link>
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:Title>Item 2</d:Title>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

---

**OR** If you want user or group title from SharePoint site directly, you can query hidden User Information List using endpoint like:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items?$select=Title,Id
```

Comment: @peter How would the call format look if the Person or Group column was called the following: 'Dean of School/College, Vice President of Division or Vice Provost'

Comment: You have to use the internal name of your column in place of `PersonColumn` in above endpoint. Follow this to find internal name: https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html